# Write output of pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader to pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large CSV file which I am reading using user defined input "num_rows" (number of rows) in parts of chunks, using "chunksize" argument, which returns "pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader" object as follows:

```
num_rows = int(input("Enter number of rows to be processed

chunk = pd.read_csv("large_file.csv", chunksize = number_of_rows)

for data_chunk in chunk:
    # some processing
    # Finally, write back results to Pandas DataFrame-
    data_chunk["new_column"] = some_precalculated_value
```

However, this approach clearly does not work. How do I go about writing back the results of the chunks back to the original Pandas DataFrame, which in my case happens to be "large_file.csv"?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you only need the first `number_of_rows`? If so you can use the `nrows` argument in the `read_csv` method.

Comment: No, I need to read the CSV file in chunks, say every 5000 rows in a file containing 1000000 rows (an example). Then there will 200 such chunks (each chunk containing 5000 rows)

Answer (score 1):

What you did will not modify the csv because each `data_chunk` is not linked to the original data.
You can write each `data_chunk` to a separate csv file

```
reader = pd.read_csv("large_file.csv", chunksize = number_of_rows)

for i, data_chunk in enumerate(reader):
    data_chunk["new_column"] = some_precalculated_value
    data_chunk.to_csv("large_file_part{}.csv".format(i))
```

To use larger than memory data like a dataframe, you can use [dask](https://dask.org/). If you did the above, then you should just have to do:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.read_csv("large_file_part*.csv")
ddf.to_csv("large_file.csv", single_file=True)
```

Alternatively, you can initially load your dataframe with dask, and performs computations with it.
It automatically splits your dataframe into partitions, and performs operations just like it is a regular pandas dataframe, in a lazy fashion.